# Explanation on Function literal with receiver in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, builder

I was following this link https://kotlin.link/articles/DSL-builder-in-Kotlin.html to understand the builder implementation in Kotlin. I didn't understand the methods inside Builder class. Method `name()` receives Extension Function as an argument which receives nothing and returns String. And the caller calls `name { "ABC" }`. If the caller is passing String to `name` method, how does it translate to an Extension method which returns String ?

I tried following Kotlin documentation for Function literals with receivers but all had samples which returns `Unit` or refers to DSL Builders. Tried googling it as well to understand but no luck in grasping the concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call to `name { "ABC" }` is a combination of two Kotlin conventions.

There is a convention that if the last parameter to a function is a function you can omit the parenthesis. Also since there are no parameters to the lambda, `"ABC"` is what is returned by it.

So the caller is actually passing a lambda in the form `name ({() -> "ABC"})`, rather than a String.

Looking at the example in the link, it doesn't look like the receiver is necessary for `name()`, which is why it could be misleading.